# java.sql.SQLException: [DataDirect][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Unhandled token type: Unknown token: 0x50

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm using jdk 1.4 and trying to connect SQL server 2000.

I am getting following exception.

Please provide solution to fix this

```
java.sql.SQLException: [DataDirect][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Unhandled token type: Unknown token: 0x50
```

Comment: try agiain after upgrading to 1.6

Answer (score 1):

this - I just googled it. looks like you have to upgrade.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378422.aspx